# Custom login redirect failed in hook_user_login

Tags: 7, hooks, users, redirection

I'm trying to redirect to the user edit page just after the user logged in from the login block in the sidebar. I implemented [hook_user_login](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.api.php/function/hook_user_login/7), but no luck. It seems to me that `drupal_goto()` or `$edit['rediect']` cannot take precedence over `$_GET['destination']`

```
function mymodule_user_login(&$edit, $account){
    if ( user role is employee and user has not completed profile yet ) {
        // both failed to redirect, although my condition is true
        $edit['redirect'] = 'user/'.$account->uid.'/edit'; 
        drupal_goto('user/'.$account->uid.'/edit');
    }
}
```

I was at my home page ( mydomain.com ) and tried to log in, but when I `exit` in my hook, I found that the URL was changed to mydomain.com/node?destination=node. My home page path is blank in site information.

**[Edit]**
My condition for redirect is that **if the logged in user has empolyee role and his profile is not completed yet**. My usecase is very similar to [this](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/44/redirect-on-login), but i don't use content profile.

I think the way of overriding $_GET['destination'] would fix my issue.

Comment: you can try `header("Location: user/".$account->uid."/edit");`, of the redirection.

Comment: Is it a drupal way? I think the drupal way for redirect is drupal_goto().

Comment: it is a PHP way to redirect using the [`header()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) function. [`drupal_goto()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_goto/7) also uses it.

Comment: I know it is a PHP way :) what I mean is that the drupal standard is to use drupal_goto() for redirect.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[drupal_goto()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_goto/7) will use `$_GET['destination']` when it is set. The following is the code used from the function.

```
  if (isset($_GET['destination']) && !url_is_external($_GET['destination'])) {
    $destination = drupal_parse_url($_GET['destination']);
    $path = $destination['path'];
    $options['query'] = $destination['query'];
    $options['fragment'] = $destination['fragment'];
  }
```

Setting `$edit['redirect']` inside `hook_user_login()` doesn't have any effect.
What you can do is changing `$_GET['destination']` in `hook_user_login()`. If you want to be sure the user is redirected to the path you set, you should be sure your hook is executed last, for example by increasing the weight of your module.

Comment: I got the fix with a single line of code `$_GET['destination'] = 'user/'.$account->uid.'/edit'` without `drupal_goto()` or `$edit['rediect']`. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

You have a shortest way,with  `rules` module .
**update:**

Steps

1- **Create a new rule**

First we have to start a new rule. For this go into the rules admin center, click on "Triggered rules" and on the tab "Add a new rule". Select the event "User has logged in", set the label "On login redirect to account page" and click "Submit".
Now we have created a new rule, which is still empty. Every condition and action that we add to this rule, will be evaluated on the event "User has logged in".

2- **add your condition**
 in condition section `add condition`, in `Select the condition to add` choose **Php**  `Execute Custom php code` (be sure your **PHP filter** is installed). check  your condition  in the condtion section.

3- **Create the redirection action**

To do so, click on the "Add an action" link, under the section "System", select the action "Page redirect" and click on "Next" button. In case you have the token module installed, the "Page redirect" action allows you to use token replacements. This allows us to place the user's id in the redirect path.
So call the action "Redirect to the users account page" and set the path user/[account:uid]. Then activate the checkbox "Force redirecting to the given path, even if a destination parameter is given" - which is necessary, because Drupal always sets a destination parameter to the current page, if a user logs in. So, that our redirection applies, we need to activate this. Check the option, and click on the "Save" button.

Comment: Can I create my condition with rules and actions? Please see my updated question. I've tried `unset`, but no success.

Comment: yes , I done this work in my project. redirect user to specify page after login(bypass defaut).

Comment: Your answer is highly appreciable. But I could not find my condition build in your steps with rules and actions. Can I?

Comment: Not need condition. after event **user has logged in **   , no need condition , and  set **page redirect** actions

Comment: I need custom redirect only if the logged-in user has empolyee role and his profile is not completed yet. It was stated in my question.

Comment: I accepted kiamlaluno's answer because I got a fix with a single line of code in my hook without using further modules installed. Thanks for your time anyway.

Comment: @SithuKyaw never mind

Answer (score 0):

I think [Login Destination](http://drupal.org/project/login_destination) module is also giving the same functionality. Apart from that it also provides some more features. It is worth to try.

Comment: You can customize Login Destination module which will redirect only to specific role also. But I haven't tried with Rules as it will not be possible to identify whether profile is completed or not using Rules

Comment: You can also Try LogintoBogaan Module